# Spring + Custom Converter + Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, converters

I got the error and have not idea where to debug.

*ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull java.util.HashMap<@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull java.lang.String, @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull java.util.Date> to type java.lang.String*

I have set my application context:

```
<mongo:mapping-converter id="mongoConverter" base-package="com.app">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
      <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.app.util.converter.HashMapToStringConverter" />
      </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.app.util.converter.StringToHashMapConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter> 


<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" id="mongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter"/>
</bean>
```

and one of my converters is:

```
public class HashMapToStringConverter implements Converter<HashMap<String,Date>, String>{
    @Override
    public String convert(HashMap<String,Date> map) {       
        if(map==null){
            throw new ConversionFailedException(TypeDescriptor.valueOf(HashMap.class), 
                    TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.class), map, null);           
        }       
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, ?> e: map.entrySet()){             
            if(!first){ 
                sb.append(",");
                first=!first;
            }            
             sb.append(e.getKey());
             sb.append("::");
             sb.append(e.getValue());           
        }       
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in a totally different situation. I had a custom decorator for  DefaultConversionService.

What I did was to call the method addConverter and added my custom converter.

I had something like:

```
public class MyConverter<Class1, Class2> {...}
```

And in another code I had:

```
DefaultConversionService cs = new MyDecoratorConversionService(new DefaultConversionService());

cs.addConverter(new MyConverter());
```